# Error while Integrating Prisma ORM in Javascript/TypeScript code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, prisma

I am having existing code which in plain javascript now I am integrating typescript and Prisma ORM in the code.

Prisma: https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/quickstart

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6", 
      "module": "commonjs", 
      "sourceMap": true, 
      "outDir": "/src", 
      "strict": true, 
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "declaration": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node", 
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true ,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowJs": true

    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", ".vscode"]
  }
```

`type_dummy.ts` FILE CODE
This code is working perfectly fine for me.

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

main()

async function main() {
     const allUsers = await prisma.client.findMany()
      console.log(allUsers)
}
```

`java_dummy.js` Javascript File Code
This is giving error

```
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client')


uploadsripts.post("/test_prisma",(req,res)=>{
    
main().catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
})

    async function main() {
        const allUsers = await PrismaClient.client.findMany()
         console.log(allUsers)
   }
    

})
```

While running the Javascript file This is the error I am getting

```
0|server  | TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.
0|server  |     at normalizeSignal (/Users/abhishek/Documents/node/ec_node/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:3828:7)
0|server  |     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
0|server  |     at getSignals (/Users/abhishek/Documents/node/ec_node/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:3823:62)
0|server  |     at getSignalsByName (/Users/abhishek/Documents/node/ec_node/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:3855:47)
0|server  |     at ../../node_modules/.pnpm/human-signals@2.1.0/node_modules/human-signals/build/src/main.js (/Users/abhishek/Documents/node/ec_node/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:3864:25)
0|server  |     at __require (/Users/abhishek/Documents/node/ec_node/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:11:51)
0|server  |     at ../../node_modules/.pnpm/execa@5.1.1/node_modules/execa/lib/error.js (/Users/abhishek/Documents/node/ec_node/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:3906:29)
0|server  |     at __require (/Users/abhishek/Documents/node/ec_node/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:11:51)
0|server  |     at ../../node_modules/.pnpm/execa@5.1.1/node_modules/execa/index.js (/Users/abhishek/Documents/node/ec_node/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:4635:21)
0|server  |     at __require (/Users/abhishek/Documents/node/ec_node/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:11:51)
0|server  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/abhishek/Documents/node/ec_node/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:20119:28)
0|server  |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
0|server  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
0|server  |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
0|server  |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
0|server  |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
```

Comment: Can you please share the relevant code block that throws this error?

Comment: @RaphaelEtim when I add this statement import statement in my file `const { PrismaClient } = require("@prisma/client");` this throws error

Comment: Can you please share the full code in that file?

Comment: @RaphaelEtim that file does not having anything else in it except this import

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproduction so i can reproduce this?

Comment: I am using this code in my Javascript file 
const { PrismaClient } = require("@prisma/client");

Comment: @RaphaelEtim I am trying to integrate typescript and prisma orm with my existing JS project along with

Comment: @RaphaelEtim Please check my updated post. I have added some more details to it.

Comment: Hey @RaphaelEtim ??

Comment: In your `java_dummy.js` file, can you first create an instance of `PrismaClient` and use the instance to perform the `findMany` query? i.e const prisma = new PrismaClient();

Comment: @RaphaelEtim I am facing same issue I have tried what you suggested

Comment: Can you please share the repository link with me so i can reproduce it and help you with it?